# three tables per row using bootstrap grid

Tags: php, html, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to print 3 tables per row on a page but I am not sure how to do it using bootstrap grid layout.

This is what I have but it prints all tables vertically

```
foreach($allmonths as $ind){
     echo "<table>";
     //echo "rest of table";
     echo "</table>";

  }
```

Comment: Well I want 12 tables totals. 3 per row, total rows would be 4 but i want to use the twiiter bootstrap grid system so everything gets align correctly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you simply need to use the default Bootstrap classes as shown here, https://getbootstrap.com/examples/grid/.

**Quick example:** (this is 3 column)

```
foreach($allmonths as $ind){
 echo '<div class="col-md-4">';
 echo '<table>{{ content here }}</table>';
 echo '</div>';
```

}

Make sure to put row into the appropriate class (.row). More information here, http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid

Comment: in this 3 tables will be printed in single row so we will need to use 6 'col-md-6' class for the div, then we will have two tables horizontally

Comment: No worries @JacobRuvalcaba!